# how to create a google analytics report with userid and pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

I want to know the page views of each user in my application based on userid as shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K54C5.png)

I have created a report with page title and userid.

I am not able to add user id/ pages in metrices.